# Redis time() sometimes returns time in the future

Tags: node.js, redis

In the Node.js code below, `timeDiff` is sometimes negative (about 1% of the time). That is, Redis `time()` sometimes returns time a few hundred milliseconds in the future, compared to the `Date.now()`, even though the Redis instance is located on the same AWS virtual machine and `Date.now()` is called after successfully receiving the response from Redis.

Is this something expected? Could it be caused by NTP, given the frequency and the difference (sometimes close to one second)?

Unfortunately, I couldn't even find source code for Redis time() function, so help finding it would be useful as well.

```
const redis = require("redis");
const Bluebird = require("bluebird");

Bluebird.promisifyAll(redis);

const redisClient = redis.createClient(LOCAL_PORT, LOCAL_HOST);

function runNext() { 
    logRedisLatency().finally(() => { 
       setTimeout(runNext, 20 * 1000);
    });
}

function logRedisLatency() { 
    return redisClient.timeAsync().then((data) => { 
       const timeDiff = Date.now() - parseRedisTime(data);
       console.log(timeDiff);
    });
}

function parseRedisTime(data) {

    const seconds = parseInt(data[0], 10);
    const milliseconds = parseInt(data[1].substr(0, 3), 10);
    const time = (seconds * 1000) + milliseconds;

    return time;
}

runNext();
```

Comment: Which version of redis module do you use? What's the `timeAsync` function and what should it do?

Comment: I've just edited the code to add Bluebird.promisifyAll(redis); call. This call adds "timeAsync" function, working exactly as "time", but returning a Promise instead.

Comment: redis server version: 3.0.4
npm module version: 0.12.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [redis docs for time function](https://redis.io/commands/time), this function return an array containing two value:

- unix time in seconds.
- microseconds.

As you know the microsecond value can be a number between 0 to 999999. In your code you are calculating milliseconds from the first 3 digits of microseconds!

The problem is just here!!!

**To calculate milliseconds you should divide microseconds by 1000**

for example when microseconds is `52369`, it means that the milliseconds is `52`, but in your code it calculated as `523`!

you can do something like this:

```
const milliseconds = parseInt(data[1], 10)/1000|0;
```

Comment: What a good catch, even if so obvious in retrospect! Thank you very much!